# Stopping streamed Comet connections being buffered by a proxy or reverse proxy?

Tags: http, proxy, comet, reverse-proxy, grizzly

I have a chat-like application which uses Grizzly Comet in Glassfish and the HTTP streaming ("forever iframe") technique. It works when the browser is directly connected, but not if there is a reverse proxy in between them. It seems the reverse proxy is buffering the Javascript Comet event stream - if you open the proxied Comet event stream URL in Chrome, you can see that nothing is being received.

How can I disable this buffering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

do

```
response.getWriter().println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
```

before writing anything else to the response writer.

I don't think this is specified anywhere, but I'm basically relying on the dumbness of proxies compared to browsers.